# my image doesn't display on screen when i try to get it from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to get an image from api and display it to screen i recieve the addrees and set it to state
when i log the state it is null
this is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    baseUrl
      .get(`/api/v1/questions/${id}/edit`)
      .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        const data = response.data.data.data;
        console.log(data);
    
        setImageUrlQuestion(`https://panel.farostaha.com${data.question}`);
        console.log(`https://panel.farostaha.com${data.question}`);
        console.log(imageUrlQuestion);

        setImageUrlAnswer(`https://panel.farostaha.com${data.answer}`);
        setSelectedBookOption({ value: data.book.id, label: data.book.name });
        setSelectedSubjectOption({
          value: data.subject.id,
          label: data.subject.name,
        });
```

other parts works correctly but the images in the state are null

Comment: can you call the api using relative path url pattern and see the results, I mean chage ` .get(`/api/v1/questions/${id}/edit`)` to ` .get(`api/v1/questions/${id}/edit`)`
if that didn't help provide a demo link containing your demo project.

Comment: i get the result and see the picture with that url
i save it to state 
and src should read the state and show the image
but state is null

Comment: can you give a demo of your component?
also add the second parameter for useEffect hook. add an array like this:
`useEffect(()=>{.... your code... },[ ])`

Comment: sorry i dont now how to give you a demo 
this is part of that code
at the end i have an array

Comment: please add your demo app here so I can check it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dubinsky-eesef

Comment: thank you mahdi 
i copied the component to the app file 
you can see the code 
but the complete project is just too big

Comment: please make sure your changes are applied to the file. I cannot see any changes.